# Image moving side to side

Tags: java, libgdx

My question is I'm creating a game where I have to get an image moving from one side of the screen to the other, and then coming back from the same side of the screen. For example I have an image of a jellyfish, it starts moving from the right side of the screen, to the left side, and then I want it to come back from the right side. I'm stuck and don't know what to do. I'm using LIBGDX and JAVA.

```
My code so far is :

package gdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    Sprite sprite;
    float fGrav, fVelo, fX, fY;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("JellyFish.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(img);
        sprite.setScale(0.3f);
        fX=0;
        fY=0;

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();



    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first step would be figuring out how to do repeat something at some interval. From there you figure out how to change the position of an image, which will allow you to move it in *one* direction. Then you create a high-level description of what you want to do ("if we're on the left, we need to start moving to the right") and break that down into smaller parts ("what does 'on the left' mean in terms of code?", "what does 'start moving to the right' mean?") and from there you write the code. Having us go through this process for you and just give you the code won't teach you much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continuously bounce an image from left to right, create an infinite loop that increases x until it is >= your display width, and then decrease it until it is <= 0, and then repeat.

I've never worked with LIBGDX, but if you wanted to use the Graphics class it would be as follows:

**Example:**

```
boolean f = true;
int x = 0;
while (f) {
    while (x <= SCREEN_WIDTH) {
        x++;
    }
    while (x >= 0) {
        x--;
    }
}
```

This should loop indefinitely.